# Converting Derived class properties to Base to make generic method

Tags: c#

I have following classes:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{

}

public class Employee:EntityBase
{
   public string Name {get;set}
   public string Address {get;set}  

}

public class Salary:EntityBase
{
   public int Basic {get;set}
   public int DA {get;set}  

}
```

I have another classes/methods to return Entity data as base type:

```
public abstarct class EntityDataBase
{
   EntityBase GetEntityData();

}

public class EmployeeData:EntityDataBase
{

   EntityBase GetEntityData()
   {
      Employee emp=new Employee();
      return emp;
   }
 }  

public class SalaryData:EntityDataBase
{

   EntityBase GetEntityData()
   {
      Salary sal=new Salary();
      return sal;
   }
 }
```

I have another class which is displaying Entity types. I want to write a generic method in the class to display data of any entities.I have implemented the class/method as following:

```
public class DisplayEntities
{ 
  public EntityDataBase entityData {get;set}
  public EntityDataBase entity {get;set}
  public DisplayData()
  {
    entity =  entityData.GetEntityData(); 
    //Display Data using some display mechanism
  } 

 }
```

I am using the code following code from Client:

```
 Employee emp = new Employee();
 EmployeeData empData = new EmployeeData();
 DisplayEntities dispEntity= new DisplayEntities();
 dispEntity.entityData =  empData;
 dispEntity.entity= emp;
 dispEntity.DisplayData();
```

But the code fails to display data for entities.How I can write a generic method to pass any entity type to a method?

Comment: Why generics? Just add an abstract method in `EntityBase`.

Comment: I don't even see how this code compiles. The statement `dispEntity.entity = emp;` should cause a compile-time error, because the `entity` field has type `EntityDataBase`, while the `emp` variable has type `Employee`, which is not `EntityDataBase` or a type derived from that class. In any case, Rotem's advice is the right answer: you don't need a generic method here (and you _certainly_ don't need reflection), you just need to add an abstract method in the base class, so that each subclass can implement the appropriate `some display mechanism` as appropriate to each.

Answer (score 0):

You can get public properties of an object using Reflection. Here is an example:

```
EntityBase entity = new Employee();
var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (var  property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name = {0}, Value = {1}",
        property.Name,
        property.GetValue(entity)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you didn't define what you understand by displaying the entity data. Do you want to display a description of the object, list of properties, memory consumption?

If you want your entity to display some basic information about the object then you probably should implement the mechanism to do that on the level of the child class (that is on the level of any class that inherits from `EntityBase`). To make sure every derived class will implement this method you should mark your `DisplayData` method as `abstract` in the parent class. Say, something like that:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public abstract string DisplayData();
}
```

Then any class derived from `EntityBase` will have to implement `DisplayData`:

```
public class Employee : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string DisplayData()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}; Address: {1}", this.Name, this.Address);
    }
}
```

And now you can use the result of the method.

As to your `DisplayEntities` class I don't see much point in implementing the class the way you did. Take a look at what happens: 1) You create a new `Employee`; 2) the employee is passed to the `DisplayEntities` class; 3) in the `DisplayEntities` class you invoke `GetEntityData` which creates another new `Employee`; 4) you override the employee from the step 1 with new one created in step 3; 5) you display employee data.

But the data will always be the same - it's always information about a newly created employee. Secondly, the `Employee` is created in steps 1 and 3. But the guy from the first step is never actually used. In your solution you only access the employee created in the third step.

Maybe it's worth reconsidering the design and the relation between `EntityBase` and `EntityDataBase`?

Having said that, if you still want your class being implemented in a generic manner, below is the implementation:

```
public class DisplayEntities<T, K>
    where T : EntityDataBase
    where K : EntityBase
{
    public T entityData { get; set; }
    public K entity { get; set; }
    public void DisplayData()
    {
        entity = (K)entityData.GetEntityData();

        Console.WriteLine(entity.DisplayData());
    }
}
```